# is it true that "Metaclass class" is just Metaclass?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I came across with the following statements:

```
(Metaclass class) new. "Uses the new of Behavior but throws error because Metaclass class is singleton"
Metaclass new. "Uses the new of Behavior"
```

I thought that `Metaclass class` is `Metaclass` then why the answers are different?
I can't seem to figure out how the method lookup works. Which hierarchy tree I need to follow? Where can I find an almost full tree that has the basic classes?

Comment: `Metaclass class` is not `Metaclass` but an instance of it. The confusion might come from the fact that `Metaclass class class == Metaclass`.

Answer (score 7):

The class/metaclass relationship is among the most complex topics in Smalltalk, yet is part of the elegance of how everything fits together in a consistent manner.

Method lookup starts in a MethodDictionary held by the class of the object (the class describes the object) and proceeds up the inheritance chain.

Generally you should not be creating new instances of Metaclass, but should let the IDE/tools make it for you as a side-effect of creating a new class (sending #'subclass:...' to an existing superclass).

You can find a tree of basic classes in your Smalltalk image. Details depend on the dialect, and Squeak should have a "Class Hierarchy Browser" that allows you to look at things.

Following is a picture that helps me visualize the relationships.

[image: Smalltalk Class Hierarchy]

Comment: but if `Number new.` than why it will use Behaviour's `new` method? As I understand, `Number` does not inheritance from `Behaviour`.

Comment: See Leandro's excellent discussion below, but the basic point is that when you send a message, the method lookup takes place in the *class* of the receiver. If the receiver is `Number` (which happens to be a `Class`), then the method lookup takes place in `Number class` (which happens to be a `Metaclass`), and that is a subclass of `Behavior`.

Answer (score 4):

There is some *magic* in the message `#new`, whose understanding requires some effort. What should call our attention is this:

> *How it is possible for a class to understand `#new` given that `#new` is implemented in `Behavior`, which is not a superclass of our class*?

For example, `Object new` creates a brand new instance of `Object` even though `Object` is not a subclass of the root implementor of `#new` (e.g., `Behavior`).

To better understand this, note that `Object new` is not a message sent to an instance of `Object` but to the class `Object`. Therefore the lookup will start at the class of `Object` which is a `Metaclass`, namely `Object class`.

It looks like the lookup mechanism through metaclasses would follow a special pathway: It starts at the alluded metaclass, say `Object class`. If it doesn't find the selector, it goes up in the inheritance hierarchy all the way up to `ProtoObject class` if needed. But, it doesn't stop here. It jumps to the abstract class `Class` to continue the lookup. From there it goes up following the hierarchy again. This happens with all messages sent to a class, not just with `#new`. In the case of `Object new`, it will find the implementor in `Behavior`.

There is something interesting observe:

> *When the lookup reaches `Class` it is no longer a class-side search, it is now an instance-side one.*

A question remains:

> *How is it possible for the lookup to jump from `ProtoObject class` to `Class`*?

Well, there is actually no jump at all. What happens is this:

```
ProtoObject superclass == nil.
```

but

```
ProtoObject class superclass == Class
```

and since the lookup sends the `#superclass` message to follow the inheritance chain, it will naturally transition from `ProtoObject class` to `Class` without having to do anything special.

The particular detail here is that for all classes, except `ProtoObject` we have

```
AnyClass class superclass == AnyClass superclass class      "<- algebraic commutativity"
```

However, for `ProtoObject` this is not the case, the superclass of `ProtoObject` is `nil` but the superclass of `ProtoObject class` is `Class`.

### Note

This also the **only** case where a `Metaclass` has a superclass which is **not** a `Metaclass`. That is precisely the exception which resolves the modeling circularity.

Comment: Took the liberty to highlight the last paragraph which is really important to understand the whole picture.